# If $a_n =\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k} $, find the generating function $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n $

Tags: linear-algebra, recurrence-relations

(This is undoubtedly a duplicate,
but I just wanted to work this out
from scratch.
The algebra and rearrangements of summations
is complicated enough
so that,
as usual,
I am hoping that
someone might have
a simpler derivation.)

Given the linear recurrence

$a_n
=\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}
$
for $n \ge m$.

Find the generating function
$A(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n
$
in terms of
$a_{0..m-1}$
and
$c_{1..m}$.

My answer is

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

My derivation.

Let
$A_j(x)
=\sum_{n=0}^{j} a_n x^n
$
for
$j = 0$ to $m-1$.

$\begin{array}\\
A(x)
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{m-1} a_n x^n+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n\sum_{k=1}^m c_k a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^n  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m}^{\infty}  x^{n-k}  a_{n-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k\sum_{n=m-k}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n}  a_{n}-\sum_{n=0}^{m-k-1}  x^{n}  a_{n})\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k(A(x)-A_{m-k-1}(x))\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)+\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA(x)-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\begin{array}\\
A(x)(1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k)
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^kA_{m-k-1}(x)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}A_{k-1}(x)\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{k=0}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k}\sum_{n=0}^{k-1} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} x^{m-k} a_n x^n\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{k=n+1}^{m-1} c_{m-k} a_n x^{n+m-k}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+m-m+1}^{n+m-n-1} c_{m-n-m+r} a_n x^{r}
\qquad r = n+m-k, k = n+m-r\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{n=0}^{m-2}\sum_{r=n+1}^{m-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=A_{m-1}(x)-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n x^{r}\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1} a_r x^r-\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}x^r\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n\\
&=a_0+\sum_{r=1}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} c_{r-n} a_n)\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{n=1}^{r} c_{n} a_{r-n})\\
&=\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore

$A(x)
=\dfrac{\sum_{r=0}^{m-1}  x^r(a_r-\sum_{k=1}^{r} c_{k} a_{r-k})}{1-\sum_{k=1}^m c_k x^k}
$.

Comment: Rather painstaking process, but I can at least confirm that the calculations are sound.

Comment: I work out the math as I enter it - never write anything down - so all the details have to be there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can turn the recurrence into a proper Cauchy product by defining $c_k = 0$ for $k=0$ and for $k>m$. Take $C(x) \equiv \sum_{k\geq 0} c_k x^k = \sum_{k=1}^mc_kx^k$ and consider 
$$A(x) C(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0} d_k x^k\tag{1}$$
where $d_n = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k a_{n-k} = \sum_{k=1}^n c_k a_{n-k}$ which reduces to $d_n = a_n$ for $n\geq m$. Now it's just a matter of splitting the sum in $(1)$ into $k<m$ and $k\geq m$ and rearranging to get the result

$$A(x) = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}[a_k - d_k]x^k}{1-C(x)} = \frac{\sum_{k=0}^{m-1}[a_k - \sum_{i=1}^k c_ia_{k-i}]x^k}{1-C(x)}$$